# CTRL-Z (Undo) After DOM modification in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I have:

1. an inputbox
2. some js code that adds suggestions for
   autocomplete.

I want: to be able to use ctrl-z.

In every other browser, when I make modifications to the value of the input, I can undo them with ctrl-z

In internet explorer, as the suggestions are added and thus the DOM is modified, no ctrl-z is available on the input.

Anyone has overcome this issue?

The closest I got was this issue in jQuery, but not much else: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7873

Comment: Have you considered updating your practices? You don't need JavaScript for this any more. [`<datalist>`](http://prntscr.com/72sbtj)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not suitable for me. As I need a very "custom" suggestions box. It needs to, at least: 1) be "per word", much like a code-editor ctrl-space kind of suggestions, 2) have some heading text and custom formating, 3) replace only part of the text when an option is selected.